# Trying to inherit hr.employee but getting error

Tags: odoo, odoo-view, odoo-12

So I'm trying to inherit hr.employee in odoo but there's an error that I don't know why since I'm doing it like in the tutorials. ([Link to the tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#inheritance))

Here's my code: in

> employee.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
""" Class Employee """
_inherit = 'hr.employee'
_description = 'A custom class of employee'

esia = fields.Float(digits=(12, 2))
cnaps = fields.Float(digits=(12, 2))
```

> employees.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_form_view">
    <field name="name">employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <notebook position="inside">
            <page string="Sécurité Sociale">
                <group>
                    <field name="cnaps"/>
                    <field name="esia"/>
                </group>
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="employee_list_action">
    <field name="name">Employees</field>
    <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
```

And what I get as error when trying to upgrade my module is:

```
Invalid model name 'hr.employee' in action definition
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean, why are you trying to modify the action which opens the view and inheriting from the XML view but doing nothing in there?

Comment: Have you defined 'hr' module in manifest file of your module?

Comment: @Amal how do we define that?

Comment: @forvas I'm going to show other fields but since I'm getting this error, I didn't put them yet

Comment: thanks @Amal, I googled how to do that and it worked, appreciate it

Comment: @Kevin so are you trying to add two new fields (`esia` and `cnaps`) to the employee form? As @Amal says, you need to have `hr` in the `depends` of the *__manifest__.py* of your module. But with the code you show there is impossible to add the fields to the view since you are inheriting from it OK but adding nothing. Are you sure it is working (if so, have you pasted here the code which is working)?

Comment: @forvas here it is:
<field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Sécurité Sociale">
                        <group>
                            <field name="cnaps"/>
                            <field name="esia"/>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>

Comment: @KevinRandriajaoson ok, now you have added the whole code, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@Amal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8492065/amal), I defined hr module in `_manifest_.py` then it worked.
Added `hr` here: `'depends': ['base', 'hr'],`

Comment: Tried, isnt working, i am using - 'depends': ['base','crm',''hr'] and still getting the same error